# Using a basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to get a basis for $L^2(\{x\}\times\mathbb{R}^{d-k})$ for all $x$

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

I am in the situation where it would be very convenient if I could take a basis $\{f_i\}_{i = 1}^\infty$ for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and manipulate it in some way to get a basis for the square-integrable functions on a collection of slices, namely $L^2(\{x\}\times\mathbb{R}^{n-k})$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$. I know of course that I could do it on for each $x$, using Gram-Schmidt, but I need to relate the bases for each $x$.

How would I best do that?

Comment: Probably, it will be easy if you consider a particular choice of basis. For example, for any $f\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ we have the Haar series representation $f=P_0f+\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\big(\int_\Bbb Rf\cdot \psi_{jk}\big)\psi_{jk}$. Here, $\{\psi_{j,k}\}_{j,k\in\Bbb Z}$ defined by $\psi_{j,k}(x):=2^{j/2}\psi(2^jx-k)$ and $\psi:=1_{[0,\frac{1}{2})}-1_{[\frac{1}{2},1)}$ and $P_0f=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\int_\Bbb R\big(1_{[0,1]}(y-k)f(y)dy\big)1_{[0,1]}(x-k)$.